# Can't spot the bug in my rotate matrix code

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I know there's an easy way using transpose to rotate a square-matrix 90 degrees, but I'm writing a solution as if I don't know that one (in other words, I want to do the swapping). The generally idea below is to swap layer by layer. The `offset` represents what layer (outward to inward) is being swapped.

Here's the algorithm (note that it is wrapped in a `class` because that's a *Leetcode* thing):

```
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, matrix):
        for start in range(len(matrix)//2):
            end = len(matrix) - start - 1

            # swap all 4 coordinates:
            for offset in range(start, end): 
                # swap top_left over top_right
                temp, matrix[start+offset][end] = matrix[start+offset][end], matrix[start][start+offset]

                # swap top_right -> bottom_right 
                temp, matrix[end][end-offset] = matrix[end][end-offset], temp

                # swap bottom_right -> bottom_left
                temp, matrix[end-offset][start] = matrix[end-offset][start], temp

                # swap bottom_left -> top_left 
                matrix[start][start+offset] = temp
```

---

This works for some hand tests with small matrices, as well as the smaller input test cases in the Leetcode submission. However, it fails on the following input:

```
[[ 2,  29,  20,  26,  16,  28],
 [12,  27,   9,  25,  13,  21],
 [32,  33,  32,   2,  28,  14],
 [13,  14,  32,  27,  22,  26],
 [33,   1,  20,   7,  21,   7],
 [ 4,  24,   1,   6,  32,  34]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[ 4,  33,  13,  32,  12,   2],
 [24,   1,  14,  33,  27,  29],
 [ 1,  20,  32,  32,   9,  20],
 [ 6,   7,  27,   2,  25,  26],
 [32,  21,  22,  28,  13,  16],
 [34,   7,  26,  14,  21,  28]]
```

My output:

```
[[ 4,  33,  13,  32,  12,   2],
 [24,   1,   7,  33,  27,  29],
 [ 1,  20,  32,   2,  14,  20],
 [ 6,  28,  32,  27,  25,  26],
 [32,  21,  22,   9,  13,  16],
 [34,   7,  26,  14,  21,  28]]
```

---

This matrix is just big enough to where it becomes tedious to walk through the algorithm by hand like I did for the smaller input cases to debug. Where is the bug in my implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `offset` is *off*, try

```
for offset in range(0, end-start):
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make that rotation, the value of i-th row and j-th column of the input matrix should be made equal to the j-th row i-th column of the output matrix (transpose) and (next step) columns should be reversed. If i were you I would define an empty matrix and (say TRANSPOSE, has the same size as the input matrix), would define 2 for loops (i in range len(matrix), and j in range len(matrix). Inside second loop I would write

```
TRANSPOSE[i][j] = matrix[j][i]
```

Now I have the matrix you want with reversed columns. Now we need to reverse columns to get what you want, so I would define another for loops with the same variables and range, and need one more empty matrix with the same size or we can use the input matrix again, let's use the input matrix in this case.

```
matrix[i][j] = TRANSPOSE[i][len(matrix) - j - 1]
```

and return `matrix`

Answer (score 1):

Your (random) test data is hard to follow and debug. It would better to use readable set.

Also seems that implementation makes excessive swaps.

It is enough to remember cell value, shift data cells in cyclic manner, retrieve remembered value.

Here is simple implementation of rotation with mat filled with sequential numbers:

```
n = 5
nm = n - 1
mat = []
for i in range(n):
    a = [x for x in range(n*i, n*i+n)]
    mat.append(a)

for i in range(n):
   (print(mat[i]))

for row in range((n + 1)//2):
    for col in range(n//2):
        t = mat[row] [col]
        mat[row][col] = mat[nm-col][row]
        mat[nm-col][row] = mat[nm-row][nm-col]
        mat[nm-row][nm - col] = mat[col][nm-row]
        mat[col][nm-row] = t    

print("")
for i in range(n):
   (print(mat[i]))

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

[20, 15, 10, 5, 0]
[21, 16, 11, 6, 1]
[22, 17, 12, 7, 2]
[23, 18, 13, 8, 3]
[24, 19, 14, 9, 4]
```